# ckeditor: different toolbar for fullscreen mode

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to have different toolbar elements for standard mode and different for fullscreen mode?

Is there a built-in option for that?

If not, is there any workaround without tweaking ckeditor.js itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that but there's no way to change the toolbar during the runtime, in any case, including fullscreen view. You need to destroy the editor `editor.destroy()` and create a new one with different configuration to have a different toolbar.

### Workaround

Though this is not straightforward, you can bypass the issue as follows, assuming `<textarea id="editor1">`:

```
// Custom config for maximized editor.
var maximizedConfig = {
    toolbarGroups: [
        {
            name: 'maximized',
            groups: [
                'basicstyles',
                'clipboard',
                'undo',
                'tools'
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var createEditor = (function() {

    var editor;

    function invokeInstance( state ) {
        // Destroy the instance if it exists.
        editor && editor.destroy();

        // Create a new instance
        editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', CKEDITOR.tools.extend( {
            on: {
                instanceReady: function () {
                    // If it wasn't maximized, maximize the instance.
                    if ( state === CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF )
                        this.execCommand( 'maximize' );

                    // When clicking maximize button, create a new instance
                    // with a desired maximization state.
                    this.commands.maximize.once( 'exec', function( evt ) {
                        CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout( function( state ) {
                            createEditor( state );
                        }, 0, null, this.state );

                        return false;
                    } );
                }
            }

            // Use different configs according to the maximization state.
        }, state === CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF ? maximizedConfig : {} ) );
    };

    return function( state ) {
        // If there's some working instance of the editor...
        if ( editor ) {
            // If it was maximized...
            if ( state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON ) {

                // Create the new instance once de-maximized.
                editor.once( 'maximize', function( evt ) {
                    invokeInstance( state );
                } );

                // Un-maximize the instance.
                editor.execCommand( 'maximize' );
            }

            // If it wasn't maximized, basically create a new one.
            else
                invokeInstance( state );
        }

        // If there is NO working instance, create a new one.
        else
            invokeInstance();
    };
})();

// Create the first editor.
createEditor();
```

### Some words of explanation

This code observes *maximize* button click, and creates a **new**, maximized editor instance with **custom toolbar config**, when user clicks the button.

If the instance is already maximized, clicking the button creates a **new** "minimized" instance with **default toolbar config**.

### Final notes

**Note #1**: Since a new instance is always created, the selection is lost (lots of code needs to be added to preserve it) and other stuff also is gone. This is some kind of a trade-off.

**Note #2**: Since CKEditor 4.1, the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) feature is implemented. It means that changing the toolbar will disable editor features and accordingly modify the edited contents, e.g. no link button → no link feature → no links in contents → `<a>` tags stripped out.

If you want to preserve the contents when changing toolbars, you got to adjust `config.allowedContent` or `config.extraAllowedContent` in your configurations (see the [official documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)).

I hope this will help you ;)

Comment: neat, but but waiting for some help I went for more hackish approach: CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
    toolbar: [some tools here]
    , on: {
 maximize: function(e){
     if (e.data==1) { //fullscreen (1)
  //jQuery css show menu elements
     } else { //reg. screen (2)
  //jQuery css hide menu elements
     }
 }
    }
});